# Knockout js - beforeRemove animation while adding items to observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a problem with knockout js and displaying an observable array as a list; When adding an item while the beforeRemove animation is running, the removed element is moved to the bottom of the list instead of staying in its position until the animation has finished and the element is removed.

Here is a jsfiddle to explain the problem a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/bPP5Q/8/

Anyone know how i could solve this?

javascript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var ViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.data = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.removeLine = function (elem) {
            if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $(elem).remove();
            });
        }

        self.addLine = function (elem) {
            if (elem.nodeType === 1) 
                $(elem).hide().fadeIn(3000);
        }

        self.removeItem = function() {
            self.data.remove(function(item) { return item.test && item.test == 2; });   
        }

        self.addItem = function() {
            self.data.splice(1, 0, { test: 9 }); 
        }

        self.addremove = function () {
            self.removeItem();
            var id = setInterval(function() {
                self.addItem();
                clearInterval(id);
            },1000);
        }
    }

    var vm = new ViewModel([{ test: 9 }, { test: 2 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }]);

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button" data-bind="click: addremove">Click</button>
<table id="grid">
    <tbody data-bind='template: { foreach: data, afterAdd: addLine, beforeRemove: removeLine }'>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: test"></td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works properly in 2.1. In 2.2 we added functionality to recognize that an item was moved rather than removing it and adding it back. It looks like this is causing an issue for the case that you are working with. I will look into it a bit more.

Comment: I downgraded to 2.1 and it works great, but having some other problems instead that didnt exist in 2.2 so if this could be solved any other way that would be great!

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue with Knockout 3.0, you can see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/davertron/3ucVg/1/

Comment: @davertron What's wrong in your example? seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Ah, I see, if you quickly remove multiple elements it breaks. This is covered at knockout's issue tracker: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/790

Comment: asfasjkhfaksjjdfh [replied-to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828688/knockout-js-beforeremove-animation-while-adding-items-to-observable-array#comment34127765_14828688)

Answer (score 1):

Your function "addItem" is executed after 1 second (setInterval 1000 ms) so the "self.data" contains a new element while the animation fadeout is not complete (that's require 3000 ms). That's explicate your problem.

To resolve this problem you must make the same interval for "addItem" as the "fadeout", for your exemple it's 3000.
The code becomes :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var ViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.data = ko.observableArray(data);
        self.removeLine = function (elem) {
            if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).fadeOut(3000, function () {
                $(elem).remove();
            });
        }

        self.addLine = function (elem) {
            if (elem.nodeType === 1) 
                $(elem).hide().fadeIn(3000);
        }

        self.removeItem = function() {
            self.data.remove(function(item) { return item.test && item.test == 2; });   
        }

        self.addItem = function() {
            self.data.splice(1, 0, { test: 9 }); 
        }

        self.addremove = function () {
            self.removeItem();
            var id = setInterval(function() {
                self.addItem();
                clearInterval(id);
            },3000); // the same interval as the "fadeout"
        }
    }

    var vm = new ViewModel([{ test: 9 }, { test: 2 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { test: 1 }]);

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, if possible, you want to do all of your changes to the observable array in a single operation. For example, instead of adding and/or removing elements individually, you want to update the entire observable array at once, perhaps using ko.utils.arrayFilter to assign a filtered version of the observableArray back to itself.

```
self.data( ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.data(), function(x) {
    return shouldKeepElement(x);
}) );
```

If this is not possible (as is probably the case for you), you'll need to delay the adding of the item into the array until the remove animation is complete. This will probably involve an elaborate system of "levers and pulleys", so the resulting code is going to be pretty undesirable. The user experience will possibly also suffer, since "fast" user actions are going to need to be queued or disallowed.

Obviously an ideal solution is that this gets addressed in the next release of knockout. Until then, you can either "downgrade" to 2.1, or make [a small patch](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/790#issue-9803689) to the existing knockout codebase. I can't vouch for this patch, and it may have undesirable consequences, but it should be a good stop-gap for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the timing of addItem -- you need to wait for the animation to end before beginning the process of adding the new item.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bPP5Q/26/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// this runs after the window loads
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.removeLine = function (elem) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $(elem).remove();
            self.addItem();
        });
    }

    self.addLine = function (elem) {
        if (elem.nodeType === 1) 
            $(elem).hide().fadeIn(3000);
    }

    self.removeItem = function() {
        self.data.remove(function(item) { return item.test && item.test == 2; });   
    }

    self.addItem = function() {
        self.data.splice(1, 0, { test: 9 }); 
    }

    self.addremove = function () {
        self.removeItem();
    }
}


var vm = new ViewModel([{
    test: 9
}, {
    test: 2
}, {
    test: 1
}, {
    test: 1
}, {
    test: 1
}, {
    test: 1
}, {
    test: 1
}]);

ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing 'splice' and knockout's 'array.remove' may cause unexpected behavior, you'd better handling it consistently, for example, only use 'splice' like below:

```
                self.addItem = function () {
                    var index = $.map(self.data(), function (item, index) {
                        if (item.test && item.test == 2) {
                            return index;
                        }
                    })[0];
                    self.data.splice(index + 1, 0, { test: 9 });
                    self.data.splice(index, 1);
                }

                self.addremove = function () {
                    //self.removeItem();
                    var id = setInterval(function () {
                        self.addItem();
                        clearInterval(id);
                    }, 1000);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem described here was fixed in 3.4.0. see https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/790

Comment: Since this question has attracted many views and quite a few votes, perhaps this answer would actually be better as an edit to the question to let future people know that it is now not applicable. Otherwise it should be a comment to the original question. When you have enough reputation you can comment on questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the beforeAdd binding to remove the item as you display the added element

** EDIT **

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/janarde/U6Um5/5/

```
<button id="button" data-bind="click: addremove">Click</button>
<table id="grid">
    <tbody data-bind='template: { foreach: data, afterAdd: addLine, beforeAdd: removeLine }'>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: test"></td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Cyriuz wants to know how the removed item can continue to be displayed in place as it's exit animation plays.

Answer (score -1):

updated your example that I think is as expected only aumeti time to add the item to 1 second to 3

```
self.removeItem();
var id = setInterval(function() {
  self.addItem();
  clearInterval(id);
},3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bPP5Q/15/

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem. The point of the code you've changed was to demonstrate a scenario in which the problem occurs. Your change just altered the scenario so the problem didn't manifest.